# Check if any item in one array is contained in any item in another array

Tags: php, arrays, privileges

I have an array of subscriptions/plans (access levels):

```
define('PLAN_A', 0); // 0001    
define('PLAN_B', 2); // 0010        
define('PLAN_C', 4); // 0100        
define('PLAN_D', 8); // 1000        
define('PLAN_E', 16); // 10000
```

A user can be subscribed to one or more plans.

```
$user_one = array(PLAN_A, PLAN_C); // is subscribed to two plans
$user_two = array(PLAN_C);         // is only subscribed to one plan
```

A 'process' requires a certain subecription plan level - or multiple plan levels:

```
$process_1 = array(PLAN_B); // requires only PLAN_B subscripton
$process_2 = array(PLAN_B, PLAN_D); // requires either PLAN_B or PLAN_C subscription
```

I want to check if `$user_one` has the 'authority' to access `$process_1`, and separately check if `$user_one` has authority to access $`process_2` . And do the same check for `$user_two`. ("Authority" is if the user has the subscription plan required by the process.)

It looks like I need to check if any user plan subscription (one or more) is contained in the subscription requirements of the processes.

I tried using bitwise checking (which is why the PLANs have binary values), but that will only work for the check of `$process_1` . How do I check if `$user_1` has access to `$process_2` ?   Or, how to check if any value of the user array is contained in any value of the process requirement array?

Comment: you probably want https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php and also check others like array_diff etc

Comment: Does something like this answer your problem? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/181594f46a72535b24679279d2f31fa3a73cdfe3 (Just updated with small fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since one of the users (**jirarium**) copies my comment and posts it as an answer, I might as well do it myself and actually get the credit for my piece of code, and not let someone who just copies and pastes other peoples codes claim it as his own.

Here is the function I made yesterday. You input the user & process; It will then iterate through all of the users values (or plans in this case) and check if any one of them is contained in the array of process values you included. Basically check if any value of the user array is contained in any value of the process requirement array, exactly what you wanted.

It will return a true or false that can be used in an `if` statement

```php
<?php
    define('PLAN_A', 1);  //  0001  <-- corrected
    define('PLAN_B', 2);  //  0010        
    define('PLAN_C', 4);  //  0100        
    define('PLAN_D', 8);  //  1000        
    define('PLAN_E', 16); // 10000
    define('PLAN_F', 32); // 10000
    
    $user_one = array(PLAN_A, PLAN_C);
    $user_two = array(PLAN_C);
    $user_three = array(PLAN_F, PLAN_D);
    
    $process_1 = array(PLAN_B);
    $process_2 = array(PLAN_B, PLAN_D);

    function check($user, $process){
        foreach($user as $pl){
            if(in_array($pl, $process)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Usage:

```php
    if(check($user_one, $process_1)){
        echo 'true';
    }else{
        echo 'false';
    }
```

Live Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83d8d135b03d584713738b56db40ecc21e9f4ddd

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer - and putting the 'check' process as a function - makes it very easy to adapt for my application. The example in the sandbox was helpful as it allowed me to easily test other combinations. I had been struggling with this a full day trying to get a bitwise thing to work, but your solution is excellent and works just as needed.

Comment: @RickHellewell You're welcome bud :) I am glad I was able to help! and also I probably should've posted it as an answer at first instead of a comment on your question so that is my bad, you probably would've seen it sooner :L

Comment: Saw it soon enough due to time zones (and sleep). Next issue is storing and retreiving user access roles - to get the user permissions into a $user_x array. Researching that.

Comment: Maybe store it somewhere as json?

Comment: Currently trying out a serialize/universalize of an array into a medium-blob in the table. Seems to work. I suppose I could json it, but this seems to work OK.

Comment: If you pretend you invented the `in_array` function then all what you said about me is correct , please have some respect to people who try to help without showing off .

Comment: Yes "we all know".

Comment: [Comment Poaching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269913/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

You can use some function to do the work , something like this :

```
function UserPlanHaveRequiredSub($user_plans,$process): bool
    {
    foreach($user_plans as $plan){
        if (in_array($plan,$process)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
   }
```

Then you can just pass user plans and process like this :

```
$result = UserPlanHaveRequiredSub($user_one,$process_2 );
var_dump($result);// will return true or false .
```